# how to format a string value containing date to yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: java

I have a  string variable, showing date value  as ddmmyyyy(04112013).I want to format this string value to yyyy.mm.dd (2013.11.04).which is the best way to do this in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat#parse() to parse a String in a certain pattern into a Date.

```
String oldstring = "04112013";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(oldstring);
```

Use SimpleDateFormat#format() to format a Date into a String in a certain pattern.

```
String newstring = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(date);
System.out.println(newstring);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: oh my god! ty for telling me! :)